# Upstart: How to run a "stop" before stopping other services?

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, startup, upstart

I recently found out about the [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) "service starter" that Ubuntu is using and that is (apparently) the future to start/stop jobs in Linux.

It's pretty new to me (I was used to the old SysV system of putting scripts in `/etc/rc[X].d/`) and I don't know if it's possible to stop a service (call the service with the "`stop`" parameter, although the parameter doesn't seem to matter that much anymore) before other services are stopped.

I want to run a small script that informs a remote server that the machine is shutting down. I need to run that script before the `dbus` and the `network` services are taken down. Is there any way of doing it with Upstart? Or... better said, what is the way of doing that through Upstart `.conf` files? (I'm sure there's a way, I just don't know it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `pre-stop` directive in upstart config file,

Which will be executed before taking down the service, e.g

```
pre-stop script
   blabla
end script
```

Answer (score 0):

if i don't mistake you can do it with same `init q`, Of course Upstart replaced of inittab and sysv but runlevels are stay.......

Comment: Right... the problem is that the dbus seems to be shutting off before the scripts in /etc/rcX.d are read (where my script is) so when I try to run the script, I gen an error. Thank you for the suggestion, though

Answer (score 0):

Use the following file contents:

```
start on runlevel [016] or stopping dbus or deconfiguring-networking

task

exec /path/to/your_script.sh
```